Restrictions on a Jewess who was baptised as a child
What are the restrictions for a Jewish girl (husband born Jewish, wife converted to Judaism) who was baptized Christian as a child (not by choice) and then converts back to Judaism (by choice) (re marrying a Cohen, etc)?

Thank you, Rabbi!

You said "wife converted to Judaism." You mean the child's mother was a convert? If she's then going and baptizing her kids, there's a strong chance the whole conversion was a sham, in which case the daughter is a straight-up convert.

Your more interesting question is -- assume a girl had two Jewish parents but was then baptized ... (let's say for example the parents handed her off to a Christian family during the Holocaust...)

Let’s not make assumptions.  Or, for the sake of the question - let’s assume it was not a sham conversion, but a kosher, orthodox conversion and there were circumstances (Holocaust, if you must), and the child was then baptized as a Christian.  My question remains the same.  Sources will also be helpful.  Thanks.

Then please take the red herrings about the parents out of the question.

@Shalom the mother being a convert is a red herring to this question?

Simple question: "Deborah was born to two Jewish parents, then baptized, then went to the mikvah as part of reconnecting to Judaism. Can she marry a kohen?" The question as I'm hearing it posed: "Mary converted to Judaism to marry Harold; a year later, Mary had a daughter, Deborah, and promptly baptized her behind Harold's back." In which case we can reasonably question whether Mary really was sincere in converting to Judaism, and thus whether Deborah was really born Jewish. So yes, red herring.

@Shalom I don't think an accidental extrapolation need be a red herring. It's not unheard of that a halachicly converted Jewess (or Jew) later reverts, but that doesn't cancel her status as a Jewess. Her being a convert might be important information, so excluding that information isn't ideal. Best if the question just locks it down to "valid legit convert"

Thank you Rabbi.  This is not simply an academic exercise.  It’s a real life situation for which I’m trying to learn the Halacha.  The information I provided is what is important.

If this Jewess, who was baptized as a child, ever had sexual intercourse with a non-Jew (vaginal or anal), then she would not be allowed to marry someone with the status of a "Cohen".
